# Filter matrix when entries are close

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am using Matlab and I have a problem with filtering a matrix. The matrix is filled with rising numbers, I want to delete all entries in the matrix which are closer then a given intervall to the entry before (n-1).

I did this already with a for loop, and it worked. The problem is, it took *five hours* to compute!

**my code**:

```
for i=2:y   
    if ((arrMaster1(i-1)+deadtime)<arrMaster1(i))
        j=j+1;
        arrMaster1cut(j,3)=int64(arrMaster1(i));
    else
    end   
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can do all of your subtractions at once, rather than individual elements each loop. This can be made even easier by using [`diff`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) like so

```
diffs = diff(arrMaster1(1:y));
% equivalent to: diffs = arrMaster1(2:y) - arrMaster1(1:y-1);
```

Then create a logical array, to test if your differences are greater than `deadtime`:

```
keepthese = [true, diffs > deadtime]; 
% outputs vector like [1 0 1 1 1 0 ...], of length y, where 1 is true and 0 is false
% diffs is of length y-1, so extra "true" is needed.
% There is a "true" in the place of every element you want to keep.
```

Finally, create your output:

```
arrMaster1cut = int64(arrMaster1(keepthese));
% This is called logical indexing, you're choosing all elements of
% arrMaster1 where keepthese has the value 1 / true
```

**All together**:

```
diffs = diff(arrMaster1(1:y));                 % Get differences for tolerencing
keepthese = [true, diffs > deadtime];          % Get indices to keep
arrMaster1cut = int64(arrMaster1(keepthese));  % Create output
```

**Edit note**

The `keepthese` vector is a *row* vector, hence concatenation with a comma. If `arrMaster1` is a column vector, then `diffs` will be too, so instead use a semicolon

```
keepthese = [true; diffs > deadtime];          % Get indices to keep (column vector)
```

---

**A note on indexing**

Logical indexing vs normal indexing. Let's say we wanted to pull the 1st, 2nd and 4th elements from a 5 element matrix. We could use two methods:

```
 elements = mymatrix([1,2,4]);
 elements = mymatrix(logical([1,1,0,1,0])); % logical converts 1/0 to true/false
```

Obviously, the second approach (logical indexing) isn't as clear in this example. However, when used above it allows us to avoid a call to the `find` function, which would convert the logical index into a numbered vector:

```
find([1,1,0,1,0]); % = [1,2,4]
```

Therefore, we gain a speed advantage.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @sophieastro no problem, I'm curious how much the time came down from 5 hours?!

Comment: Sry again, I was maybe to fast! Your explaination is very good, but the code still has a problem:

Comment: Error in ==> cut_test at 2
keepthese = [true, diffs > deadtime];          %
Get indices to keep

Comment: Do I have to define the keepthese matrix beforehand?

Comment: @sophieastro, nope I was just doing that for clarity, you could just do `int64(arrMaster1([true, diffs > deadtime]));`, or even the whole thing in a one-liner: `arrMaster1cut = int64(arrMaster1([true, diff(arrMaster1(1:y))>deadtime));`. But shortening code won't fix your error, it will produce the same result! What is the error?

Comment: @sophieastro see my edit, that may fix your problem.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you again Wolfie :)! The semicolon fixed the error! The code is now by a factor of 5000 faster!!! cheers sophie

Answer (score 0):

i don't have all your code so this is just a guess, but your code maybe run so slow because you don't pre-allocate memory for `arrMaster1cut`, and you change it's size in each iteration.

moreover, you can vectorize the entire code using `diff`:

```
% random arrMaster1 array
y = 100;
arrMaster1 = randi(100,[1 y]);
deadtime = 5;
% differences vector
d = diff(arrMaster1);
% differences greater than deadtime
idxs = find(d > deadtime);
% produce arrMaster1cut
arrMaster1cut1 = int64(arrMaster1(idxs+1));
% your method
j = 0;
arrMaster1cut2 = [];
for i=2:y
    if ((arrMaster1(i-1)+deadtime)<arrMaster1(i))
        j=j+1;
        arrMaster1cut2(j)=int64(arrMaster1(i));
    else
    end
end
% check for equal results
isequal(arrMaster1cut2, arrMaster1cut1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much !